# AJAX return from SmartyStreets API

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, smartystreets

I am having trouble actually returning any kind of object using this AJAX call. I know I am doing something wrong, but I have no idea where. I hope someone can help me I am looking to return an element in the object "zip". I would like to have any response really, but I can not get anything back.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#submit').click(function() {
                var result = $('#resultDiv')
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://us-street.api.smartystreets.com/street-address',
                    method: 'get',
                    data: {
                        auth-id='your-auth-id',
                        auth-token='your-auth-token',
                        street=$('#street'),
                        city=$('#city'),
                        state=$('#state')
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        if (data = null)
                        {
                          result.html('You failed');
                        }
                        else {
                          result.html('Match:' + data.components[0].zipcode)
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <title>SSTest</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 style="text-align:center"> Welcome to Address Check </h1>
        <form action="#" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="street">Street</label>
                <input type="text" id="street" class="form-control" name="street">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="city">City</label>
                <input type="text" id="city" class="form-control" name="city">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="state">State</label>
                <input type="text" id="state" class="form-control" name="state">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <div id="resultDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You really should not be posting your auth-id and token. It would be a good idea to delete those from your account and create a new pair.

Comment: I've masked the authentication.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using a GET call, you can test this in the browser first AND make sure you are getting a response before you start wrapping it in a JQuery call.

`https://us-street.api.smartystreets.com/street-address?auth-id=[your-auth-id]&auth-token=[your-auth-token]&street=SOMETHING&state=SOMETHING&city=SOMETHING`

If you get a non-result, then consult the API to see if you are passing the correct parameters.

Using the [DOCS](https://smartystreets.com/docs/cloud/us-street-api), this call returns data for your API Keys -

`https://us-street.api.smartystreets.com/street-address?auth-id=[your-auth-id]&auth-token=[your-auth-token]&street=1600+amphitheatre+pkwy&city=mountain+view&state=CA&candidates=10`

This JQuery Get HTML example gets a response -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.get("https://us-street.api.smartystreets.com/street-address?auth-id=[your-auth-id]&auth-token=[your-auth-token]&street=1600+amphitheatre+pkwy&city=mountain+view&state=CA&candidates=10", function(data, status){
            alert("zipcode: " + JSON.stringify(data));
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Send an HTTP GET request to a page and get the result back</button>

</body>
</html>
```

You should be able to build from that as you refine your JQuery understanding to get exactly what you need.

Comment: I have tested it and confirmed that those credentials and information do return an object but I don't think I am getting a response at all. I thought it may have been spacing issues and checked that and still got nothing in return.

Comment: Remember, that in order to get a response, if the address is invalid, you have to set the match parameter to "invalid"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a handful of errors with your code and fixed them here in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xe08bazs/2/). Here are the list of errors you had.

1. Don't include your auth-id, auth-token in public code. You're giving away your address lookups by doing this. You should go remove these from your account and generate new ones.
2. In your original `success` function you didn't do a compare. You should use `==` here. Actually, the API will never send back null for data on success so you don't even need this here anymore. Use the `error` function instead.
3. The data object passed in the ajax call is done incorrectly. You should not be using `=`, instead use `:`.
4. In the data object you should call `.val()` after the jQuery selectors to get the values entered into those fields.
5. `data.components[0].zipcode` should be `data[0].components.zipcode`. The api will return back a data array of objects. `components` is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

The auth-id and token should only be used when used from server side.
It is clearly mentioned not to expose the auth-id and auth-token in the documentation.

I used the FETCH API from Javascript and the code looks like this:

```
var key = '' //your embedded key here
var street = encodeURIComponent('1600 amphitheatre pkwy');
var city = encodeURIComponent('mountain view');
var state = 'CA';
var url = 'https://us-street.api.smartystreets.com/street-address?street=' + street + '&city=' + city + '&state=' + state + '&key=' + key;

const response = await fetch(url)
const responseData = await response.json()
```